# How to find first instance of duplicated instances and tag it on a different column in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, aggregate

I have the following data sorted by `ID` then `Date`. `Signal_Tag` is 1 when there is a positive signal.

```
ID          Date    Signal_Tag 
1123    2020-01-03  0          
1123    2020-01-03  1          
1123    2020-06-09  1          
1123    2020-06-10  1          
2234    2019-01-01  0          
2234    2019-01-01  0          
2234    2019-01-01  1          
2234    2019-01-01  1          
2234    2019-01-02  1          
2234    2019-01-02  1          
2234    2019-01-02  0
```

I like to create a new variable `Daily_Signal_Tag` that represents the first daily signal. `Signal_Tag` can have more than one `1`'s on the same day for the same person. But `Daily_Signal_Tag` can only have one `1` on the same day for the same person.

I understand in Pandas, I can do it with multiple steps, i.e., remove duplicate, aggregate and re-merge, but I would like to do it in perhaps one (or few) step, while being able to generate the `Daily_Signal_Tag` column. The desired output data looks like the following:

```
ID          Date    Signal_Tag      Daily_Signal_Tag
1123    2020-01-03  0               0
1123    2020-01-03  1               1
1123    2020-06-09  1               1
1123    2020-06-10  1               1
2234    2019-01-01  0               0
2234    2019-01-01  0               0
2234    2019-01-01  1               1
2234    2019-01-01  1               0
2234    2019-01-02  1               1
2234    2019-01-02  1               0
2234    2019-01-02  0               0
```

Comment: Since most Pandas operations consist of multiple steps that happen behind the scenes, it's not clear that you gain much from doing this in one step compared to two straightforward steps as you've described them. Are you looking for more compact code, or a more efficient method that runs faster with a large data frame? You could modify the Pandas library yourself with a method that will do this in one step if you'd like. Are you looking specifically for a speed increase?

Comment: Code compactness is the first benefit I am looking for, speed increase will be a side benefit (but not necessary as long as it doesn't slow it down). I might have simplified the number of steps if it's done my normal way, it will need to `copy` a df, then `drop_duplicate`, then aggregate via `pivot_table`, then flatten via `to_record`, then `merge` it with other aggregated data. So I wonder if there is a neater way in Pandas that can reduce the number of steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `pd.groupby()` with these 3 columns, take [first value from each group](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) and concatenate it to original DataFrame (and fill NaNs with `0`):

```
df = pd.concat([
        df,
        df.groupby(['ID', 'Date', 'Signal_Tag'])['Signal_Tag'].head(1).rename('Daily_Signal_Tag')
    ], axis=1).fillna(0).astype({"Daily_Signal_Tag": int})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      ID        Date  Signal_Tag  Daily_Signal_Tag
0   1123  2020-01-03           0                 0
1   1123  2020-01-03           1                 1
2   1123  2020-06-09           1                 1
3   1123  2020-06-10           1                 1
4   2234  2019-01-01           0                 0
5   2234  2019-01-01           0                 0
6   2234  2019-01-01           1                 1
7   2234  2019-01-01           1                 0
8   2234  2019-01-02           1                 1
9   2234  2019-01-02           1                 0
10  2234  2019-01-02           0                 0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get the first index of each signal with [`Groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and then remove the values for all other indices with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

```
m = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])['Signal_Tag'].transform('idxmax')
df['Daily_Signal_Tag'] = df['Signal_Tag'].where(df.index == m, other = 0)
```